# How to add Google Calendar as a Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, google, calendar, google-calendar

Despite that I am able to create Unity launchers for **Google Keep, Play Music, Inbox & Drawing; the same does not work for Google Calendar**. I added Google Calendar to my Chrome as an application from [extensions.google.com](http://extensions.google.com) as I did for others.

Any ideas about how to add Google Calendar into Unity **as a launcher**?

*p.s. I do not (want to) use Ubuntu Web Apps.*

Comment: This will not work as the app is basically nothing more than a link in your apps-menu opening Google Calendar in a new browser tab. . There would be no difference to a Ubuntu Web App.

Comment: I know - I want to reach my calendar with a single-click to improve my productivity. Most of the time I - as a software developer - have too many tabs on my browser window & so I want to open some apps to open separately like Google Keep. @Christian

Comment: Did you try to create a custom App-Shortcut in Chrome itself? 
Sounds like this is exactly what you want. You can place a shortcut to any website in your  menu and it will open in a seperate instance with only the website (no tabs, no menus).

Comment: thanks @Christian; it was exactly what I was looking for. It will be better if you post it as answer instead of comment. Then I will be able to accept it the answer of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every Chrome-app brings its own menu-entry.

But you can create so-called app-shortcuts from Chrome-menu for any website you want. Those apps are placed on your desktop and/or application-menu and start in an own minimal browser-instance without menus, tabs or an address-bar.

Comment: Creating the app-shortcut is very good but putting it to the unity launcher would be specially useful for productivity for it would then be accessible through keyboard the default unity launcher shortcuts Win+Number.

Comment: Uh? You can add those to the launcher, otherwise my suggestion would be nonsense...this was the point of the question

Comment: On 12.04 the calendar shortcut appears in the dash but I can't drag it to pin it on the launcher...